# Event ID 15021 HttpEvent on a wildcard SSL certificate but only get the error on a couple sites

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, ssl-certificate-errors

I have IIS running on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have a wildcard SSL certificate on 14 subdomains. I'm seeing a lot of errors in the Event Viewer.

Event ID: 15021 Source: HttpEvent

An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint my.domain.com:443.  The error status code is contained within the returned data.

However, I'm only getting this error on 2 of the sites, the other 12 are not logging this error. The 2 sites creating this error load up fine in a web browser. I've checked the binding in IIS and they both have the wildcard SSL selected.

If there is a certificate problem, I would expect this error coming from all 14 sites, not just 2 of them.

Though those 2 sites load fine in a browser, I'm not comfortable seeing thousands of these errors on our two biggest sites.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Can you try to analyze all mappings and see if there is anything obvious? You should also check "the returned data" from the event log entry, as that error code has a meaning.

Comment: Everything _appears_ okay in the bindings. I tried to copy and paste it, but it's too long for a comment. I'm a newbie to serverfault. I'm not sure the best way to share the event log.

Is there a way to find out what the 'returned data' is, or is that what I'm seeing in the event viewer details?

Comment: Also, When I visit the two sites that are putting errors in the event viewer, the pages load just fine, no indication of a problem. When I view the certificate in my browser, it is the correct on and the names and everything match.

Comment: I just noticed something interesting. When I run `netsh http show sslcert`. I see entries for the two sites throwing the error, however, on the othr sites using the same wildcar SSL cert, they aren't listed at all (and also not throwing an error). I hope this helps!!